# How do I add Two UILabels in my UIScrollView for the iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
myscrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
myscrollview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myscrollview];
CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+500);
[myscrollview setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];

lblluckyno = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 200, 50)];

lblfirstmsg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 295, 800)];
```

But I don't know My Firstmasg length.... after that lblfirstmsg I want to add second lblsecongmgs.... So how can I add?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you want to add the two labels to you scrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set first label and set it content you can call `[lblfirstmsg sizeToFit];` to fit frame to its content. Then you can add your second UIlabel next to the first one `[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblfirstmsg.frame.origin.x + lblfirstmsg.frame.size.width, lblfirstmsg.frame.origin.y, 200, 50)];`

Answer (score 0):

```
[myscrollview addSUbview:lblluckyno];
```

and same way add 2nd label.

Answer (score 0):

This is your scroll view code.

```
myscrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
myscrollview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myscrollview];
[myscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+500);];
```

After you set two label With CGRect and add in Scroll View

```
[myScrollView addSubView:lblluckyno];
```

......

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mayur P Bhansali,

You can find the position and dimension of your first label like so:

```
lblluckyno = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 200, 50)];

UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(lblluckyno.frame.origin.x + lblluckyno.frame.size.width, 200, 100)];
```

Each UIView has a "frame" object and this frame object has a "origin" C structure and "size" C structure. Using labelName.frame.size.width gives you the width of a frame and labelName.frame.origin.x gives you the X coordinate of the frame.

You could access these properties like this too:

```
[labelName frame].size.width
[labelName frame].size.origin.x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblluckyno = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 200, 50)];
lblfirstmsg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 295, 800)];
[myscrollview addSUbview:lblluckyno];
[myscrollview addSUbview:lblfirstmsg];
```